# (Heute Abend)(gehe)(ich)(ins Kino)

Tags: grammar-identification

> ***Heute Abend*** gehe ich ins Kino.

Es ist bekannt, dass das Verb immer in 2. Position kommt. Wie erkläre ich aber die 1. Position, die aus 2 Wörtern besteht *heute* und *Abend*? *Heute* ist ja ein *Temporales Adverb*, Was sagt man aber zu *Abend*?

Comment: _"Was sagt man aber zu (Abend) ?"_ Ein _Substantiv_ das die Tageszeit bezeichnet? Ich verstehe Deine Frage nicht ganz, glaube ich.

Comment: Also, man kann ein Wort zum Adverb hinzufügen, um die Zeit genauer zu beschreiben, und das ganze bleibt immer noch nur die erste Position, weil es nichts neues erwähnt hat? (außer Zeit in diesem Fall) Gibt es eine bestimmte Regel die das erklärt ?

Comment: Ehrlich gesagt bin ich mir jetzt selbst nicht mehr sicher, ob _heute_ zu _Abend_ gehört, oder zu _(heute) gehe ich_. Ich glaube ersteres, kann aber keine Regel nennen die das begründen würde.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Es ist eben die *Vorfeld*-Regel, die besagt, daß im Hauptsatz nur *ein* Element for dem finiten Verb steht. Weiterer Beleg ist, daß die Konstruktion "heute Abend" nicht umgekehrt oder aufgelöst werden kann, sondern ebenso zusammengehört wie etwa "diesen Abend".

Comment: @Kilian Dann beantwortet das die Frage denke ich.

Answer (score 6):

Wie du schon richtig bemerkst, bezieht sich die Regel, dass das Verb im deutschen Hauptsatz in der zweiten Position steht, nicht auf die Worte. sondern auf [**phrasale Einheiten**](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrase_(Linguistik)), oder **Phrasen**:

> Als Phrase bezeichnet man in der Linguistik eine syntaktische Einheit, die abgeschlossen, also „syntaktisch gesättigt“ ist, im Gegensatz zu Einheiten, denen noch Ergänzungen fehlen

Zu den Details, was genau eine Phrase ist, und wie im konkreten Fall die Phrasengrenze zu bestimmen ist, siehe den verlinkten Wikipedia-Artikel.

Im Beispiel

> Der Gärtner gießt die Blumen.

ist *[der Gärtner]* eine zusammengesetzte [**Nominalphrase**](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominalphrase). Es ist nicht ungewöhnlich, dass Phrasen aus mehreren Worten zusammengesetzt sind. Das kann mitunter sehr lang und komplex werden:

> Das große schnelle rote Auto, das wir gestern probegefahren sind, gefällt mir.

Hier ist *[Das große schnelle rote Auto, das wir gestern probegefahren sind]* eine komplexe Nominalphrase, deren Kern das Nomen *Auto* ist.

In konkreten Fall deiner Frage bezeichnet man *Heute Abend* als [**Adverbialphrase**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbial_phrase), die zusammengesetzt ist aus *heute* und *Abend*. Auch hier kann man sich noch komplexere Varianten vorstellen:

> Heute Abend, jedoch nicht vor 21 Uhr, und auch nur, wenn du mitkommst, und es nicht regnet, gehe ich ins Kino.

Hier wäre *[Heute Abend, jedoch nicht vor 21 Uhr, und auch nur, wenn du mitkommst, und es nicht regnet]* ebenfalls eine komplexe Adverbialphrase.

Answer (score -1):

Wenn das Verb *immer* in der zweiten Position kommt, dann auch in der Determinativ-Phrase "Heute Abend". Die Phrase insgesamt besetzt dann den ersten Platz im Satz.

"Heute Abend gehe ich ins Kino" könnte wiederum selbst als Subjekt  in einen anderen Matrixsatz eingearbeitet werden.

Ganz richtig ist das offensichtlich nicht, darüber zerbrechen sich andere den Kopf.

Richtig müsste es wohl heißen *heut zu Abend*. Vgl. *heutzutage* (sowie Engl. *today*, French *ajour d'hui*).

Da dies zusammengeschrieben wird, wird es offensichtlich als univerbierte Phrase aufzufassen sein.

Comment: Wenn ich es richtig sehe, wird die Frage (_Wie erkläre ich aber die 1. Position, die aus 2 Wörtern besteht heute und Abend?_) hier nicht wirklich beantwortet. In der Frage geht es m.E. darum, warum die zitierte Regel hier eingehalten wird, auch wenn es sich um zwei Worte handelt. Zu sagen, dass die Regel eingehalten wird, weil sie immer gilt, ist in meinen Augen dann zirkulär und löst das Problem des OP nicht.